# why is the first for loop inside S function running infinitely in the below node js program?

Tags: javascript, node.js

please check the below code and explain why the for loop is running infinitely when i am providing same 9 digit phone number in the input more than once.
I am changing the content of **numberData** in the nested for loop but shouldn't be a problem and pushing of element is done after the nested for loop in **numberData** so I am confused why its happening can anyone explain:

```
    var str = "00:01:07,400-234-090\n00:05:01,701-080-080\n00:05:00,400-234-090\n00:01:06,701-080-080\n00:01:06,701-080-000"

    console.log(solution(str))

    function solution(S) {

        var totalCost = 0
        var lineArray = S.split('\n')

        var numberData = []
        /*{
            number = 0,
            duration = 0,
            cost = 0
        }*/


        console.log(lineArray)
        for (var i = 0; i < lineArray.length; i++) {

            console.log(lineArray.length, i);
            var dataArray = lineArray[i].split(',')
            var number = dataArray[1]
            var duration = dataArray[0]

            var timeArray = duration.split(':')

            var hours = +(timeArray[0])
            var min = +(timeArray[1])
            var sec = +(timeArray[2])

            var numberPresent = false
            var totalDuration = hours * 60 * 60 + min * 60 + sec //in Seconds
            var cost = 0;

            if (min < 5) {
                cost = min * 60 + sec
            } else {
                if (sec == 0)
                    cost = min * 150
                else
                    cost = (min + 1) * 150
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < numberData.length; i++) {
                if (numberData[i].number == number) {
                    numberData[i].duration += totalDuration
                    numberData[i].cost += cost
                    numberPresent = true
                }
            }
            if (!numberPresent)
                numberData.push({
                    number: number,
                    duration: totalDuration,
                    cost: cost
                })

        }

        var maxDurationIndex = 0
        totalCost += numberData[0].cost

        for (var i = 1; i < numberData.length; i++) {
            if (numberData[i].duration > numberData[maxDurationIndex])
                maxDurationIndex = i;

            if (numberData[i].duration == numberData[maxDurationIndex]) {
                var currentNumericNumber = getNumericNumber(numberData[i])
                var maxIndexNumber = getNumericNumber(numberData[maxDurationIndex])

                if (currentNumericNumber > maxIndexNumber)
                    maxDurationIndex = i;

            }
            totalCost += numberData[i].cost
        }

        totalCost = totalCost - (+numberData[maxDurationIndex].cost)

        return totalCost

        function getNumericNumber(numberString) {
            var numberArray = numberString.split('-')
            var string = '';

            for (var i = 0; i < numberArray.length; i++) {
                string += numberArray[i];
            }

            return +string;

        }


    }
```

You can test it by providing distinct phone numbers in the input then it works perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your inner loop is resetting the value of `i` to `numberData.length` in every iteration of outer loop. Use different variable for inner loop on `numberData` like `j`

```
 for(var j=0; j<numberData.length; j++)
 {
     if(numberData[j].number == number)
     {
        numberData[j].duration+= totalDuration
        numberData[j].cost +=cost
        numberPresent = true
     }
 }
```

Or simply use `filter` and `map`

```
numberPresent = numberData.filter( s => s.number == number ).map( s => {
   s.duration += totalDuration;
   s.cost += cost;
   return s;
}).length > 0
```

Comment: There is no sense of filtering and mapping and than only taling the length.

Comment: How else would you increment the duration and cost of those values whose number is same as the value in number property?

Comment: can you explain why the inner loop was resetting the value of i to numberData.length since the "i" scope of inner loop was inside of that loop itself while the outer loops "i" was kind of global for the inner loop, so y it was changing the value of outside loop's "i"

Comment: Scope of var is enclosing function, not the block.